# Iterating react nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to iterate and render data from a nested JSON object. I can access the first layer of data but can't access the nested data. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". I understand why the this.state.coinData is undefined but cant put it into code. Please Help!!

```js
class CoinList extend Component {
    //...
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coinData: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const apiKey = ####################;

        fetch('https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=' + apiKey +"&interval=1d")
        .then(response => response.json()) 
        .then(data => this.setState({ coinData: data })) 
        .catch(error => console.log(error)) 
      } 

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="Table-container">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> h1 </th>
                            <th> h2 </th>
                            <th> h3 </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.coinData.map((coin) =>
                            <tr key={coin.id}>
                                <td> {coin.currency} </td>
                                <td> {coin.rank} </td>
                                <td>  </td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default CoinList;
```

JSON DATA that I'm trying to access:
[image]

Comment: coinData is not an array in your example, it looks like an object...check it in debugger

Comment: Can you post more of the `coinData` array? I don't see any of the properties you're trying to access (name, currency, rank) in that JSON so you should get undefined errors for all of those - unless you're just posting a small snippet of the array?

Comment: This is probably a typo, but just in case... that's not "id" in the JSON example, it's "1d"

Comment: no the id is not a typo, and ive posted the JSON data above!!, im trying to acess this.state.coinData["1d"].volume

Comment: @Barryman9000 ive posted more the json Data!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're rendering with a .map method in your tbody before you call the API and populate the empty array in state via componentDidMount.

Try adding a conditional to check whether coinData array has any values before mapping (eg. only if the array has values, run the map code). This way the page will render , then your component will mount and the API will get called and populate the array in state, and then the page will re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Using a different sample API, I'm not having any problems getting your code to run, even when I delay the response from the API. Any chance you have a typo somewhere or your API isn't returning anything?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-meitner-dfo65)

Comment: im tryna return the nested object items